# Automatic image scroller for a website heading

Tags: html, scroller

I am trying to build a looped scrolling website header text like the one on the Google homepage here - https://careers.google.com/d/

I have tried to code it but I am having no luck at all. Would really appreciate some help please, thank you.

[image]

[image]

Comment: `i have tried to code it` Can you show some examples that you're having problems with ?

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask]; this is neither a code-writing nor tutorial service. If you have code that isn't working, give a [mre] with a more specific problem than *"having no luck"*.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is [transform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/transform). At least from the example you gave.

Create your element to 'scroll'.

```
<div id="element"><h1>Code<h1></div>
```

Then add some javascript to it to apply some position change.

```
  var element = document.querySelector("#element");
  setTimeout(function() {
    element.style.transform = "translateY(100px)";
  }, 200);
```

From here we can make it animated with CSS so its scrolling down instead.

```
#element {
    position: absolute;
    transition: transform 3s linear;
    transform: translateY(0px);
    will-change: transform;
}
```

This is an example of how to move one element down.. You can wash and repeat for the second element you wan to move.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uzrcqp01/)

[Further Fiddle with more example](https://jsfiddle.net/uzrcqp01/11/)